# XAML adding text based on a trigger

Tags: xaml

```
<dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}" AutoGenerateColumns="None" ColumnGeneratorTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ColumnTemplateSelector}" dependencyProperties:BestFitColumn.IsEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}">
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Priority" Header="{x:Static meta:MetaCommon.Importance}">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image>
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SmallIcon}" TargetType="Image">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.Priority}" Value="H">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{x:Static helper:IconHelper.HighImportance}" />
                                                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Static meta:MetaCommon.High}" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to add text in the case where RowData.Row.Priority=H. I can't seem to find any way myself and was wondering if I just missed something or if have to create a work around and do something outside of this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your DataTrigger under DataTemplate.Triggers.

Have it set the Visibility for a new TextBlock with the text you want.

```
<DataTemplate>
<Grid>
<Image/>
<TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```